# Using Class Types in Static Methods

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to create a base Model that will be extended by a the specific model class with an interface describing its properties.

In the base Model class there should be a static factory() function instantiates the model from the static context and returns type with the specific model + base model + specified interface.

The problem is that I am getting the error in the static function `U extends Model<T>` saying T: *Static members cannot reference class type parameters.*

**Interface Event**

```
interface Event {
  id: number;
}
```

**Base Event Model**

```
export class Model<T> {

  public static factory<U extends Model<T>>(this: { new(): U }, data: any): U {
    return Object.assign(new this(), data);
  }
}
```

**Event Model**

`export class EventModel extends Model<Event> {}`

The goal is the return type to be EventModel which includes all the properties of Event.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `T` parameter because it doesn't have any meaning in static methods, change your code like so:

```
export class Model<T> {
  public static factor<U>(this: { new(): Model<U> }, data: any): Model<U> {
    return Object.assign(new this(), data)
  }
}
```